# Understanding variables with structs C programming

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I need some assistance understanding how variables of a typedef work with structs

```
/*This is the Struct, with a new type Program*/
typedef struct prog{
    char move[MAXNUMTOKENS][MAXTOKENSIZE];
    int cm; 
}Program;

Program prog;   // new variable of type Program that has an array and an int
```

My question is what does this next statement do, does it initialize the `int cm` in the structs to zero ?

```
prog.cm=0;
```

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. Although I would call it "assigns" not "initializes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of a struct as a template for a new object.

The line `Program prog` is creating a new structure object based on the template defined at the top.

So `prog.cm=0;` means that yes you are initializing that specific objects cm field to zero.

The typedef is there simply so you dont have to write `struct prog 'variableName'` when you want to create a new struct object